# Qual a melhor maneira de ler propriedades de entidades no "Include" com nomes similiares?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Eu tenho a seguinte consulta:

```
            var recs = (from p in _db.Fichas
                    .Include(c => c.Tipo01)
                    .Include(c => c.Tipo02)
                    .Include(c => c.Tipo03)
                    .Include(c => c.Pessoa01)
                    .Include(c => c.Pessoa02)
                    .Include(c => c.Pessoa03)
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    where p.Id == 100
                    select p).FirstOrDefault();
```

Com base na consulta acima, estou obtendo e lendo (acredito que de maneira equivocada) os valores das seguintes propriedades:

```
        var nome1 = recs.Pessoa01 != null ? recs.Pessoa01.Nome : null;
        var nome2 = recs.Pessoa02 != null ? recs.Pessoa02.Nome : null;
        var nome3 = recs.Pessoa03 != null ? recs.Pessoa03.Nome : null;
        var tip1 = recs.Tipo01 != null ? recs.Tipo01.ModeloA : null;
        var tip2 = recs.Tipo02 != null ? recs.Tipo02.ModeloA : null;
```

Algum colega poderia me ajudar e me mostrar uma maneira mais decente de executar essa tarefa?

Forte abraço
Hugo

Answer (score 0):

Pela sua pergunta não dá pra ter certeza do que você pretende...
Mas se o objetivo é remover essas condições ternárias e considerando que o seu código está preparado para trabalhar com esses valores nulos. Você pode escrever essas declarações de formas mais simples e legível.

```
    var nome1 = recs?.Pessoa01?.Nome;
    var nome2 = recs?.Pessoa02?.Nome;
    var nome3 = recs?.Pessoa03?.Nome;
    var tip1 = recs?.Tipo01?.ModeloA;
    var tip2 = recs?.Tipo02?.ModeloA;
```

Também recomendo que você reavalie o nome das suas propriedades, variáveis e objetos... `Pessoa01`, `nome1`, `Tipo01` e `tip1` não fazem nenhum sentido semântico. E se o seu domínio está estruturado dessa forma, é melhor você rever o seu projeto desde a base.

Comment: Bom dia, Leandro.  Muito obrigado pelo seu feedback.  Estou dando manutenção em sistema de terceiros.  Na realidade, para economizar linhas de desenvolvimento, eu pensei em algo como um loop para ler as propriedades e entidades. Por exemplo, ao invés de ter que obter o "Nome" das entidades "Pessoa01, Pessoa02 e etc"; talvez eu pudesse fazer um loop concatenando um contador e assim fazer a leitura.

Comment: Algo assim:  rec.Pessoa(i+1).Nome Entendeu?